# How don't show excess vertical lines in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vetur

I have 2 files, first .phtml

Screen of code from there:

[image]

And second file .vue:

[image]

Using the red arrows in the screenshot above, I want to show that there are extra vertical lines in the Vue file, which, it seems, do not connect anything.

There are no such lines in the .phtml file

How can I remove them?

Comment: the text colors are also not in the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its work for me:

```
"editor.detectIndentation": false
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set that in the settings file as stated in the [docs of VSCode settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) 
Press `Ctrl + Shift + p`, type `settings` and go to `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)` to open `User Settings`, and add this:

```
  "editor.renderIndentGuides": false,
```

Comment: In all other files (except vue) everything works correctly. If I use this, lines like this disappear everywhere. It's about the Vetur plugin and prettier formatter, but I don't know what to change

Comment: It's the same stuff everywhere. Maybe try closing the tabs of the open vue files, then restarting VSC. Sometimes changed take a moment to "kick in". I've had similar struggle.

Comment: @Alexander You can define settings for specific languageId's